# converting cshell to bash

Tags: bash, csh

I am trying to translate the following cshell command to bash
but I am not sure what it does and how I can translate it
to bash.

```
./runall |& fold -w 80 |& tee ${log_file}
```

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo |& bar` executes `foo` with its stdout and stderr piped to the stdin of `bar`.

The bash equivalent is `foo 2>&1 | bar`.

So for your command, it should be (untested):

```
./runall 2>&1 | fold -w 80 2>&1 | tee ${log_file}
```

(The curly braces in `${log_file}` aren't really necessary, but they're harmless, and some consider them to be a good idea; that's true for both csh and bash.)